# Cancelling scheduled Web audio

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I've understood what I can of [A Tale of Two Clocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/), which describes a method of scheduling for Web audio applications with live editing, like drum machines, and I'm confused about a crucial aspect.

A primary motivator for the technique is that once a `AudioBufferSourceNode` has been scheduled to play with `start()`, it can't be cancelled.

But if I call `stop()` on a `AudioBufferSourceNodes` before it's scheduled to play, it never plays, and therefore can be cancelled. So why is this technique necessary? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the OP was asking "why don't I just schedule all the notes in advance, and then cancel all the remaining ones (via .stop()) if I want to stop?"

You can do this, actually.  For small sequences, this might be an okay approach.  However:

If you want the ability to cancel them, you'll need to hang on to references to each AudioBufferSourceNode separately - and a 16th-note hihat pattern alone, at 140bpm, is 2800 notes (=AudioBufferSourceNodes) for a 5-minute song.  That's also (for the entire song) possibly a substantial set of memory to be allocating and deallocating all at once.  For longer sequences, it may be less attractive.

The same is particularly true if you're making any live changes to the sequence playback - for example, if you want to change tempo, you'll need to cancel all the remaining notes, and reschedule them.

The primary motivation for the technique I detailed in ATOTC is at the end of the second section: "In short, because you will need the flexibility to change tempo or parameters like frequency or gain (or stop scheduling altogether), you don’t want to push too many audio events into the queue - or, more accurately, you don’t want to look ahead too far in time, because you may want to change that scheduling entirely."  While it's true I mentioned cancelling, that's an afterthought, really.

If you're working with relatively short sequences, and you don't care about a little extra memory being used, the EASIEST thing to do is simply create a GainNode, connect it to the destination, and set up all your AudioBufferSourceNodes to connect to that GainNode.  Explicitly don't keep references to your ABSNs, but keep one to the GainNode - and if you want to cancel, just disconnect the GainNode and release it.  Nothing further will play to the destination, and everything will eventually be freed.  (I mentioned this in section two, also, although it might read as a little derogatory.  For smaller applications it's okay.)

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit is that `audioBufferSourceNode.start(someTimeInTheFuture)` is sample accurate. This is the reason why it is preferred over `setTimeout(() => audioBufferSourceNode.start(), someTimeInTheFuture)` which is not accurate at all.

Due to the inner workings of the Web Audio API it is always a good idea to schedule something ahead of time if possible. Whenever `start()` is called on an `AudioBufferSourceNode` that command has to travel from the main thread to the audio thread where it will then be executed. This takes a little while which means it may arrive too late on the audio thread in case you want to start something immediately.